# Estimate on expression involving elements in the unit disc in $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $|\lambda|<1, Re\lambda < 0, Im\lambda > 0$. What is the largest lower bound independent of $\lambda$ on the expression

$$Re\lambda - \frac{2\pi}{n+2}Im\lambda$$ where $n$ is a positive integer? If you like, stipulate that $n$ be as large as you need for the problem to make sense, though make it as small of a lower bound on $n$ as you can, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = -\Re(\lambda), y = \Im(\lambda)$ and $c = \frac{2\pi}{n+2}$. The above problem is then equivalent to $$\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& {\text{minimize}}
& &  -x -cy\\
& \text{subject to}
& & x^2 + y^2 < 1 \\ & & & x>0 \\ & & & y>0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}$$

This is a pretty tame convex program, and has a standard solution via the KKT conditions. In particular, the infimum is $-\sqrt{1+c^2}$, and the point $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^2}} (-1,c)$ is the limit point of the region where this value is attained.

Comment: Excellent! How would I figure a similar problem out for myself in the future?

Comment: The formulation as a convex program is of course sitting right in the question, seeing it might require a bit of experience with optimisation. If you mean 'how would one solve such an optimisation problem?' instead, that's a furiously vast subject. [Boyd & Vandenberghe's free book](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) is a great textbook that builds the theory up from the bottom, but it might be worthwhile to take a class on the same (usually called non-linear or convex optimisation).

Comment: Which kind of program would be best to solve such constraints? Is there a standard program?

Comment: Program as in on a computer? I'm pretty much a luddite, so don't really have a clue on which ones are any good, but there are literally hundreds of numerical optimisation packages. The only one I've used is the one bundled in Matlab/Octave, which does the just fine for my requirements but YMMV. If you instead want symbolic optimisation packages, I'm afraid I've never used any, but it might be worth a MSE question.

Comment: So how did you figure this out if not by a computer program?

Comment: If I wanted to minimize the same quantity with $\frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{2}$ added to the front, how would I go about it?

Comment: RIght, so that's the meat of my first comment. If you'd just prefer a quick-fire intro to the techniques try googling for "method of lagrange multipliers" and "KKT conditions" and reading through some of the course handout pdfs that pop-up. If you follow through to the link included, the web-page also lists a MOOC that you can go through. It all depends on how much of the theory you'd like to get into, though.

Comment: Oh, and wolfram alpha happily takes care of at least this and other simple problems symbolically. Try entering "maximise {your function} subject to {constraint 1, constraint 2, ...}". If you'd like to optimise complicated functions you're probably better off asking on the site, although I now suspect mathematica might have the functionality.

Comment: I appreciate your responses. Mathematica can minimize as well, no?

Comment: I posted my new question as a separate problem on the site. If you could take a look, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: The answer by Michael suffices, I think. Note that the optimality conditions he uses are also known as the KKT conditions, which I mentioned previously.